# Long running tasks in Pyramid web app

Tags: python, queue, pyramid, background-process, pylons

I need to run some tasks in background of web app (checking the code out, etc) without blocking the views.

The twist in typical `Queue`/`Celery` scenario is that I have to ensure that the tasks will complete, surviving even web app crash or restart until those tasks complete, whatever their final result.

I was thinking about recording parameters for `multiprocessing.Pool` in a database and starting all the incomplete tasks at webapp restart. It's doable, but I'm wondering if there's a simpler or more cost-effective aproach?

UPDATE: Why not Celery itself? Well, I used Celery in some projects and it's really a great solution, but for this task it's on the big side: it requires a separate server, communication, etc., while all I need is spawning a few processes/threads, doing some work in them (`git clone ...`, `svn co ...`) and checking whether they succeeded or failed. Another issue is that I need the solution to be as small as possible since I have to make it follow elaborate corporate guidelines, procedures, etc., and the human administrative and bureaucratic overhead I'd have to go through to get Celery onboard is something I'd prefer to avoid if I can.

Comment: You mentioned Celery - what makes you to dismiss it and invent your own solution? The task looks like a typical use case for Celery

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you to use Celery.

Celery does not require its own server, you can have a worker running on the same machine. You can also have a "poor man's queue" using an SQL database instead of a "real" queue/messaging server such as RabbitMQ - this setup would look very much like what you're describing, only with a separate process doing the long-running tasks.

The problem with starting long-running tasks from the webserver process is that in the production environment the web "workers" are normally managed by the webserver - multiple workers can be spawned or killed at any time. The viability of your approach would highly depend on the web server you're using and its configuration. Also, with multiple workers each trying to do a task you may have some concurrency issues.

Apart from Celery, another option is to look at [UWSGI's spooler subsystem](http://uwsgi-docs.readthedocs.org/en/latest/Spooler.html), especially if you're already using UWSGI.