# Pyramid debugtoolbar causing memory "leak"

Tags: python, memory-management, memory-leaks, pyramid

My pyramid app has a long-running task (~30 minutes). When debug toolbar is on, the memory usage (RSS) starts to exceed 30GB, which results in OOM killer killing the whole Python process.

When I turn debug toolbar off, RSS consistently stays below 500MB during the task run and there's no problem at all with memory use.

I can turn debugtoolbar off for development mode, however I'd like to leave it on for obvious reasons.

I'm looking for possible solutions to this problem, like:

1. turn debug toolbar off before running the task and on after it's completed
2. tell debug toolbar to "forget" tracked objects every once in a while (during running the task)
3. any other switch, flag, to debug toolbar that would reduce its memory use.

Solutions?

Comment: The beginning of your story - "My pyramid app has a long-running task (~30 minutes)" - sounds so very wrong... I see we even discussed this a year ago and I suggested to use Celery ;-)  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26195632/long-running-tasks-in-pyramid-web-app

Comment: @Sergey: it seems (wrong) at first sight, but it's not really - for the vast majority of tasks I'm running Celery is simply an overkill. I've used Celery in the past and it's a brilliant solution, but most of my tasks run in a several to a dozen seconds and I do not have to set up yet another server to run. I've used APScheduler instead to run near "in-band" (in another thread, although it supports running in separate process as well) and have been very happy with it. P.S. with debugtoolbar I have a memleak in EVERYTHING. Not just this biggish task.

Comment: My guess that it is because it logs all database calls in-memory.

Comment: Use a Python profiler like Heapy to see what leaks memory and monkey-patch debug toolbar in your application to not to take this action.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `pyramid_debugtoolbar` is implemented as a tween that captures a huge amount of state of your application. All of that state is stored in the processes memory so that when you visit the debugtoolbar you have access to that information.

However, you can turn `pyramid_debugtoolbar` off for certain paths within your application using an .ini setting:

```
debugtoolbar.exclude_prefixes
```

This is documented here: http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid-debugtoolbar/en/latest/#settings

> The debug toolbar won’t be shown and no data will be recorded if the PATH_INFO variable starts with any of the prefixes listed in this setting.

You can provide a list of paths if necessary.